# Word still compressing images when saving as PDF

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, images

I took screenshots with Grenshot in order to include them in my document and they look great in Word. However, when I save it to PDF or print the document with Microsoft Print to PDF" my images look blurry.

What I've tried:

1) When 'saving as' I click on Tools -> Compress Pictures -> Resolution: High Fidelity.

2) Printing from 'Microsoft Print to PDF'.

What else could it be and what are my options?. I'm including graphs from Power BI so it would be a mess to export all my data into excel to have graphs with good quality.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: You might try a free alternative to MS Print to PDF, such as [doPDF](https://www.dopdf.com/download.html), which does have a setting for resolution... *I could not find such a setting for the MS Print to PDF app in Windows 10.* There are [other alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/microsoft-print-to-pdf/?license=free&platform=windows), as well.

[image: doPDF resolution & scaling]